# How did “pumpkin” come to be a term of endearment?

Tags: meaning, etymology, hypocorisms

The logic of some terms of endearment is fairly clear.  *Sweetie, honey, cupcake* all refer to food treats.  However, the use of the term **pumpkin** as a tenderness seems somewhat counterintuitive.  While reasonably tasty and the basis for making some treats (pumpkin bread, pumpkin pie), on its own it is a rather prosaic vegetable. Its appearance is also not obviously in the category of beautiful flora.

Dictionary references are not much help.  Only two of the online dictionaries in *onelook.com* list the affectionate definition.  [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pumpkin) offers, without etymology or example,

> *often capital (mainly US)* a term of endearment

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pumpkin) gives one definition as

> *(US)* A term of endearment for someone small and cute.

It cites only to the lyrics of a song by John Prine from 1991, *Daddy’s Little Pumpkin*.

A search on Google for the term *little pumpkin* (a search for *pumpkin* is beyond my patience) shows a fair amount of usage in the later 20th century and the 21st century as an affectionate nickname.  One of the earliest, in that period, appears in the 1951 novel by Myron Brinig, *The Sadness in Lexington Avenue*

> *Let me hear it. Frieda, my little pumpkin, my little sugarplum*

There are few 19th century references using pumpkin, somewhat sweetly, but not quite as an endearment.

In 1867, *The Little Corporal*, a children’s magazine published a story that included

> *for Matie was almost as round as a little pumpkin*

This appears to be a straightforward description, not very complimentary, about shape.

In *Forrest’s Illustrated Juvenile Keepsake*,1851  there is reference to another apparently roundish child

> *If a little pumpkin, like Dumpy Dorcas, had rolled upon the snow, what harm would have come of it?*

In *The Child’s Friend and Family Magazine* from 1858, there is a reference to an American Indian character in a story whose English name appears to be *Little Pumpkin*.

So, whence the acceptance (by some) of **pumpkin** as an affectionate reference for the apple of your eye?

Comment: I'd wager it originated for children who were round and ruddy, then lost its dependence on physical appearance. *[Doodlebug](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doodlebug#English)* is the term of endearment most mysterious to me.

Comment: An ngram search for "punkin" might be useful here, as it's a long-standing informal variant and likely to be connected with informal uses of the word.

Comment: @tylerharms Interesting idea. Most references so far (I'm up to about 1940) are just dialects, and probably more for *punkin pie* (and hundreds of references for Riley's *When the frost is on the punkin ...*). but I did find a dead on use in 1939 in Rawlings *Yearling* referring to Jody by his grandmother.

Comment: @tylerharms And several more references in the 1940s in stories, but no guide as to how it morphed from a bland rotund vegetable to a dearly beloved.

Comment: I think this may be hard to pin down, as these terms seem to arise arbitrarily. My parents call my sister ladybug for no particular reason, and I've not run into another person who's had that nickname.

Comment: While pumpkin creates an odd image when we use it as a term of endearment, sometimes the oddness of that image enhances the endearing quality. Just a thought.

Comment: The French have _mon petit chou_ ("my little cabbage"), and I can only imagine that the Belgians have the Walloon or Flemish equivalent of "my big Brussels sprout."

Comment: In Italian when we say someone is really "zucca" we're saying that the person is extremely stupid, as in having no brain (pumpkins are often hollow), which I quite like as an insult :)

Comment: I am reminded that Prince Philip's favorite term of endearment for his wife, Queen Elizabeth II, is "cabbage".  I think that's sweet!

Comment: My mother's favorite term of endearment is "bogárkám", which translates to "my little bug". Compared to that, vegetable terms (cabbage, pumpkin) are pretty tame. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Terms of endearment reflect what the user finds desirable, and not everybody shares the (American?) view that sweets are the most pleasant food. The French *mon petit chou* means literally 'my little cabbage', Russians (sometimes) call each other 'my little wild raspberry', and several pages could be written (by someone with a strong stomach) on German food endearments; e.g. *mein Spätzle*, the name of a type of pasta, apparently derived from 'wild sparrow'. The prize as far as I know, however, goes to a respondent to a BBC enquiry for endearments:

> I am married to a Tibetan lady who calls me nyingdu-la. This translates as "most honoured poison of my heart". Adam Buckley, Hebden Bridge, UK

Comment: +1, but where did you read that Russians call each other "my little wild raspberry"? I am a native speaker of Russian but I don't recall ever calling someone (or being called) a little wild raspberry. This sound Bill-Bryson-ish, if you know what I mean :)

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան: Actually, from my Russian teacher and my grandmother (both pre-revolutionary aristocrats).

Comment: Which exact word were they using? My main question is what's the word for a little wild raspberry. малинка /malinka/?

Comment: @Armen: A few years ago now, but IIRC it was *malinkaskaya* (sorry, no Cyrillic on this keyboard). But *malinka* is not uncommon; most famously in the song 'Kalinka', though I admit rhyme may be a reason.

Comment: I think Persian “my liver” is a hot challenger for the prize.

Comment: I am not sure *chou* means 'cabbage' here. Rather it should be *chou (à la crème)* meaning 'cream puff'. At least that's what I thought before reading this, and it should make more sense, a cream puff being sweet. Maybe someone can research this.

Answer (score 2):

The *OED* has pumpkin as a term of endearment from 1900 in *Dialect Notes*:

> *Pumpkin*, a student's best girl.

This is their sense 2c. Sense 2 includes other chiefly North American colloquial and figurative uses, such as 2a) "Applied contemptuously to a person who is stupid, conceited, or self-important, or (occas.) to a stout or portly body" (1680) and 2c) "In predicative use: a person or matter of importance or consequence; an impressive thing. Esp. in some pumpkins" (1845).

Answer (score -1):

Well, don't we all like pumpkins in the fall for decoration, adds some color when the rest of nature has turned dull and brown?  Children adore going to the field and choose their favorite, and hold it in their arms proudly, it's almost a little love affair for them.  Remember Charlie Brown and the Great Pumpkin?  So perhaps that has something to do with it.  You also have sweet pea, love muffin, honeybunch, hmm, seems we relate a lot to foods!  And rather than call our sweetie cloud, tree, grass, leaf, stream, river, lake, etc., etc.  Things that are truly beautiful to the eye, but we choose food instead, it is interesting to think about.

Comment: There's the common endearments: "You're so cute/adorable/sweet, I could eat you" and "eye candy".