# What’s the difference between “cite” and “cite to”?

Tags: differences, legalese

From page 69 of Frederick Shauer’s *Thinking Like a Lawyer*:

> A New York state court may **cite to** a case decided in Vermont . . . The
>   courts are not even required to **cite to** these “authorities,” let alone follow
>   them.

Why does this use *cite to*?  Why isn’t it simply [cite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cite?q=cite)?

What are the similarites and differences?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about legal jargon, not English.

Comment: [All *cite to* citations are strictly legal ones](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22cite+to%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest), and for which the OED has no citations (yet).

Comment: @tchrist Funnily enough I came across this post from Google. I was reading another ELU post where "cite to" is used by someone who appears to be a native speaker and because I have never heard it used before and I looked it up and Google brought me here. This disproves your statement that "all cite to citations are strictly legal": ["It cites only to the lyrics of a song by John Prine from 1991, Daddy’s Little Pumpkin."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/133015)